# How do I bind an action to a "create/remove new node" event in DynaTree?

Tags: addition, dynatree

Getting started with DynaTree. I'd like to bind some code to the event which is "adding a new node". The onCreate option seems to be fired when a node is rendered for the first time. Yes, this includes when a node is created, but it also includes when the tree is loaded and rendered, and when a collapsed subtree is expanded for the first time. So it doesn't seem appropriate. The same question applies to removing a node. Where are these events?

Thanks,
Marco.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to execute code when you add a child? I did this by creating my own little function to add Nodes.

```
function addChildNode(NodeID, NodeName, ParentID){
    jQuery("#tree2").dynatree("getTree").getNodeByKey(ParentID).addChild({title: NodeName, key: NodeID});

    //Code you wish to be executed goes here

}
```

Then you simply call the function and pass in the NodeID (key), NodeName (title), ParentID (key).